# How do I host Node.js and WordPress sites on the same domain name with a different server?

Tags: wordpress, server, dns

I would like to host 2 different applications on a different server. For eg `www.example.com` redirected the `NodeJS application - Server A`  & `www.example.com/blog` redirected the `WordPress application - Server B` both applications are hosted in a different server.

is it possible to host Node.js and WordPress sites on the same domain name with a different server?

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to create a subdomain for the WordPress blog and redirect it to the new "`Server B`" which has the blog so that now it can be accessible under something like `blog.example.com` and link it to the NodeJS application on "`Server A`" within the application menu.

Example (Server A application Menu):

```
Home | About | Blog
```

When a user clicks on the blog menu item, he gets redirected to the blog on "`server B`" with ease. And on `server B` you can create a fallback "`Home`" link to redirect them back to main domain "`www.example.com`".